How to fetch the each element value as per the order of the plancode
I need table row should fetch as per the order of the Code value
Input xml I'm having:
<Group>
    <Maps>
        <Map>
            <Code>20000</Code>
        </Map>
        <Map>
            <Code>30000</Code>
        </Map>
        <Map>
            <Code>40000</Code>
        </Map>
        <Map>
            <Code>50000</Code>
        </Map>
    </Maps>
    <Details>
        <Detail>
            <Code>40000</Code>
            <Description>Variable</Description>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Code>50000</Code>
            <Description>Non-Variable</Description>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Code>30000</Code>
            <Description>Benefit</Description>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Code>20000</Code>
            <Description>Non-Benefit</Description>
        </Detail>
    </Details>
</Group>

XSL I have tried the below using the variable:
<xsl:template match="Group">
      <xsl:variable name="MapCode" select="Maps/Map/Code"/>
      <row>
         <entry>Code</entry>
         <xsl:for-each select="Maps/Map">
            <entry>
               <p>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Code"/>
               </p>
            </entry>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </row>
      <row>
         <entry>Level</entry>
         <xsl:for-each select="Details/Detail[Code=$MapCode]">
            <entry>
               <p>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
               </p>
            </entry>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </row>
      </xsl:template>

Actual Output I'm getting:
     <row>
      <entry>Code</entry>
      <entry>
         <p>20000</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>30000</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>40000</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>50000</p>
      </entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>Level</entry>
      <entry>
         <p>Variable</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>Non-Variable</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>Benefit</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>Non-Benefit</p>
      </entry>
   </row>

Expected Output Should be:
     <row>
      <entry>Code</entry>
      <entry>
         <p>20000</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>30000</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>40000</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>50000</p>
      </entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>Level</entry>
      <entry>
         <p>Non-Benefit</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>Benefit</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>Variable</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>Non-Variable</p>
      </entry>
   </row>

As per the Code order match the Description value should pick. I used the variable for Code match. But still it picking the Description value wrongly. So Description should pick as per the Code order.

Your example is ambiguous. Would it be correct to assume that Maps is the "header" and Details is a "data row" of the output table?

@michael.hor257k yes, you're right!

An example with 2 or 3 data rows would be much clearer.

I am guessing you want to do something like:
XSLT 2.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="detail-by-code" match="Detail" use="Code" />

<xsl:template match="/Group">
    <xsl:variable name="headings" select="Maps/Map" />
    <table>
        <!-- header -->
        <row>
            <xsl:for-each select="$headings">
                <entry>
                    <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Code"/>
                    </p>
                </entry>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </row>
        <!-- data -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Details">
            <xsl:variable name="current-row" select="." />
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="$headings">
                    <entry>
                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('detail-by-code', Code, $current-row)/Description"/>
                        </p>
                    </entry>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Using the following test input:
XML
<Group>
    <Maps>
        <Map>
            <Code>COLOR</Code>
        </Map>
        <Map>
            <Code>SIZE</Code>
        </Map>
        <Map>
            <Code>SHAPE</Code>
        </Map>
    </Maps>
    <Details>
        <Detail>
            <Code>SIZE</Code>
            <Description>small</Description>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Code>COLOR</Code>
            <Description>red</Description>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Code>SHAPE</Code>
            <Description>circle</Description>
        </Detail>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <Detail>
            <Code>SHAPE</Code>
            <Description>square</Description>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Code>SIZE</Code>
            <Description>medium</Description>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Code>COLOR</Code>
            <Description>blue</Description>
        </Detail>
    </Details>
</Group>

I get:
Result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
   <row>
      <entry>
         <p>COLOR</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>SIZE</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>SHAPE</p>
      </entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>
         <p>red</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>small</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>circle</p>
      </entry>
   </row>
   <row>
      <entry>
         <p>blue</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>medium</p>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <p>square</p>
      </entry>
   </row>
</table>

